# ShieldUI Grid Column min width

Tags: jquery, gridview, grid, shieldui

Is there a property or a way to specify a minimum width for a column in a ShieldUI Grid?

```
$("#grid1").shieldGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: products,
                    sort: [ { path: "['Category']['CategoryName']", desc: true } ],
                    filter: { field: "ProductID", value: "1" }
                },
                rowHover: false,
                columns: [
                "ProductName",
                { field: "['Category']['CategoryName']", title: "CategoryName", format: "{0:c}", width: "330px" },
                { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
                { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
                { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" },
                {
                    buttons: [
                            {
                                cls: "mybuttonCssClass",
                                caption: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Delete",
                                commandName: "details", // build in - edit, delete
                                click: function (rowIndex) {
                                    var grid = this;
                                    // custom actions ...
                                    console.log(grid.options);
                                    alert(rowIndex);
                                }
                            },
                        { commandName: "delete" } // delete, edit, expand
                    ]
                }
                ]
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a [minWidth property](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/columns/minwidth), described like this:

> The minimum width which the column can take when user resize it. In
>   order to use this property the resizing of the grid needs to be turned
>   on.